Is there a way to preserve the Masoretic Text of 2 Samuel 8:17?
The Masoretic Text (MT) of 2 Samuel 8:17 reads

וְצָדוֹק בֶּן־אֲחִיטוּב וַאֲחִימֶלֶךְ בֶּן־אֶבְיָתָר כֹּהֲנִים וּשְׂרָיָה סוֹפֵר׃

However this seems to contradict both 1 Samuel 22:20 and 2 Samuel 20:25 which have Evyatar as the son of Achimelech. I have seen modern translations which simply amend the text. I have not seen any traditional commentaries which even note the discrepancy. Is there any way to explain and preserve the reading of the MT?

Why not two Achimelechs - son of Evyatar and father of Evyatar? Would make sense that he named his son after his murdered father.

@Harel13 please see the verse cited, Achimelech's father's name was Achitoob. וַיִּמָּלֵט בֵּן־אֶחָד לַאֲחִימֶלֶךְ בֶּן־אֲחִטוּב וּשְׁמוֹ אֶבְיָתָר וַיִּבְרַח אַחֲרֵי דָוִד׃

I see nothing contradictory. In Shmuel 1 Achimelech senior is Evyatar's father, and in Shmuel 2 Achimelech junior is Evyatar's son. Achituv is the father of Achimelech senior.

What does Samuel 2:20:25 show? וּשְׁוָ֖א סֹפֵ֑ר וְצָד֥וֹק וְאֶבְיָתָ֖ר כֹּהֲנִֽים doesn't name evyatar's father or son

@DoubleAA 2:8:17 states that Achimelech is the Kohen, 2:20:25 states that Evyatar was. The verses in chapter 20 are ostensibly a replay from ch. 8. cf verses 23-24 in ch. 20

This would probably be easier to understand if you quoted all the relevant verses and showed the problem. Not just the one that drives the problem in your mind.

Rabbi Yitzchak Notovitz wrote that the second Achimelech was the grandson of the first.

As I wrote in the comments, it seems clear to me that there were two Achimelechs: The first was Achimelech ben Achituv, who was the kohen who met David at Nov when the latter was fleeing from Shaul. This Achimelech was ultimately slain by Doeg the Edomite at Shaul's command, along with the rest of the kohanim of Nov. His son was Evyatar, who joined David's side, until he was ousted by Shlomo for passing his allegiance to Adoniyahu. The second Achimelech was one of Evyatar's sons, and was very likely named after his grandfather. This interpretation was presented as clear fact by Rabbi Yitzchak Notovitz, a 19th-century expert on Gittin (for some information on him, see here). Indeed, there are other cases in Tanach, as demonstrated by Rabbi Notovitz, of biblical characters who were named after their ancestors. I would argue that since this interpretation is clear p'shat, commentators did not see any reason to comment on the issue.
